# C++ #define value not being read in cpp file

Tags: c++, compiler-directives

In my C++ `.h` file:

```
class foo {
#define useThis true

...
}
```

In my `.cpp` file:

```
#if useThis
... generate A code
#else
... generate B code
#endif
```

The problem is that the `#define` values are not being read in the `.cpp` file, so what is happening is both A and B are being generated.

I am including the `.h` file in the top of the `.cpp` file.

Comment: Firstly, posting real code is going to help more here. There's no way any proper compiler is going to be generating both of those (in this case, `generate B code` will be the winning branch). Secondly, use `1` instead of `true`, as `true` isn't a preprocessor value. That, or just use `#ifdef useThis` or `#if defined(useThis)` and omit the `true` value altogether.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iVXMEjUZLFjJeMSZ)

Comment: @Qix The C++ preprocessor **does** recognise `true` and `false` as the appropriate boolean values.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean value can not be used in macros for some compilers, like Visual Studio (works under g++ though). A cross compiler way should be:

```
#define useThis 1
```

Or, define a macro without value, and use `ifdef` to test if it has been defined:

```
#define useThis

#ifdef useThis
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

Comment: I've gone over this in a now-deleted answer, but [this is incorrect](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.cond). *After all replacements due to macro expansion and evaluations of defined-macro-expressions and has-include-expressions have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for true and false, are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token.* and *The resulting tokens comprise the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules of [expr.const]…*

Comment: In short, `true` is not replaced with 0 like other identifiers are. After that step, the expression `true` is evaluated according to the same rules as constant expression evaluation everywhere else in the language, satisfying the `#if` condition.

Comment: @chris Seems it is a compiler related behavior. Boolean in macro does not work for Visual Studio 2013, but works for g++.

Comment: I'm not surprised. VS has had incomplete preprocessor support for a long time. I think it will possibly be brought up to speed more toward the end of 2017, or at least after most other standardization issues like two-phase lookup.

Comment: I have tried both #define USE_THIS 1 and testing for #if USE_THIS and #define USE_THIS and testing for #ifdef USE_THIS. In both cases, the tests work in the .h file but not in the .cpp file.

Comment: @BobJones Just to be sure, did you include your `.h` file in your `.cpp` file?